# Clearing a single notification in iOS 11.2 clears them all

Tags: ios11, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest, ios11.2

Since iOS 11.2, clearing a single notification from my app seems to clear them all. I can't seem to figure out what's happening as no code was changed.

My `UNNotificationRequest` are created with GUUIDs to be universally unique (since my app allows users to create multiple alerts based on the same reminder type).

What must I be doing wrong?

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *alertContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
alertContent.categoryIdentifier = ALERT_CATEGORY_ALERTS;
alertContent.body = task.title;
alertContent.userInfo = ... a dictionary of stuff

...

NSDateComponents *dateCompos = [localGregCal components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth 
| NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | 
NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:deliveryDate];

UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *alertTrigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger 
triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:dateCompos repeats:NO];

UNNotificationRequest *notifRequest = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:NEW_GUUID
 content:alertContent trigger:alertTrigger];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be an iOS 11.2.0-.5 issue:

[rdar://36575570: iOS 11.2.2: Clearing/Action on notification causes …](https://openradar.appspot.com/36575570)

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same issue only with iOS 11.2 and now I have update my OS 11.2 to 11.3. Now it's working fine for me.

So this is the OS related bug which is resolved in iOS 11.3.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause/solution:

If you are clearing a single notification upon arrival of a silent notification without an `alert`, make sure that `aps.batch` is not set to 0. Make sure that `aps.batch` is not included in your message at all.